# WPF ItemsSource binding show only last item of list

Tags: c#, wpf, list, itemssource

How to show only last item of the list in itemssource binding ?

below is my current code.

### xaml

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UpgradeTicketStorage}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="800">
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding TicketTitle}"  Style="{StaticResource TicketSelectionSubTitle}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding TicketDescription}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource TicketSelectionSubTitle2}" FontSize="19" TextAlignment="Left"/>
             </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

from class binding i do have added 2 records which is `ticketA` and `ticketB`, how can i just display `ticketB` information ? instead of A and B

### class

```
public class UpgradeTicketDescription : ViewModelBase
    {

        public string TicketTitle { get; set; }
        public string TicketDescription { get; set; }
    }

List<UpgradeTicketDescription> _UpgradeTicketStorage;
public List<UpgradeTicketDescription> UpgradeTicketStorage
    {
        get { return _UpgradeTicketStorage; }
        set { _UpgradeTicketStorage = value; OnPropertyChanged("UpgradeTicketStorage"); }
    }
 UpgradeTicketStorage.Add(new UpgradeTicketDescription { TicketTitle = "TicketA", TicketDescription = "Observation DeckA (Single Ticket)"});
 UpgradeTicketStorage.Add(new UpgradeTicketDescription { TicketTitle = "TicketB", TicketDescription = "Observation DeckB (Single Ticket)"});
```

Comment: Why use an items control if you want to only display the last. If you really need a UpgradeTicketStorage list why not just bind to an expression property of `UpgradeTicketStorage.Last()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind to a specific item in a list you can go about it by creating a public variable you will bind to. Using what you have provided I've created an example that works for the last item in the list, all I did is create a new variable called LastItem and changed how the binding is in the project. This is just one of many ways of going about this.

**xaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="800">
  <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LastItem.TicketTitle}" TextAlignment="Left" />
  <TextBlock  Text="{Binding LastItem.TicketDescription}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="19" TextAlignment="Left"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**class**

```
public UpgradeTicketDescription LastItem
  {
  get { return UpgradeTicketStorage.Last(); }
  }
```

This provides this output:
[image]